# How Do I Solve Alert Dialog leaks from a class that is passed a context?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Alert Dialogs seem to leak if they are open and you configuration change (like rotate the device).

The solution I seen on the internet is to dismiss the dialog inside OnPause (if its not null and showing) and in OnResume (show it again).

My problem is how do I do this on a class which is passed a context (does not extend activity) and contains an alert dialog. I do not have onPause or onResume methods here

Comment: Is the custom class instantiated from your Activity?

Comment: @user3249477, yes from onCreate inside the main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your custom class is instantiated from your Activity, you can manually extend the activity's lifecycle to it. Just create a couple of methods which will be called from your activity. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyClass mMyClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mMyClass = new MyClass();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mMyClass != null) mMyClass.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mMyClass != null) mMyClass.onPause();
    }

    private class MyClass {
        protected void onResume() {
            // Create dialog
        }

        protected void onPause() {
            // Remove dialog
        }
    }

}
```

Note: In this example MyClass is an inner class just for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.